# Setting up Windows 7 64-bit for Japanese language input and display

Tags: windows-7, ime

How do I set up my computer language/keyboard to support the Japanese language? I am using Microsoft Windows 7- 64 bit OS.

Comment: Could you please be more specific - what is the OS, do you want to read Japanese or print it too?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about technology. I think it'd be better on superuser.

Answer (score 0):

For display, you do not need to do anything. Japanese fonts are installed by default for Windows 7.
For input, you will need to enable the Japanese IME.

1. Open Region and Language from Control Panel -> Clock, Language, and Region -> Region and Language.
2. Click the Keyboards and Languages tab.
3. Click Change keyboards.
4. Click the Add button.
5. From the Add Input Language, choose Japanese (Japan) and the Microsoft IME.
6. Click OK.
7. Click OK.

There is nothing special about Japanese. The same steps are true for all supported languages.